# Calculating the difference between sleep time and wake time T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an app where user can enter sleep and wake time as a number. I need a stored procedure to calculate the total hours slept for each day. E.g. If the user sleeps at 10pm, before midnight, and wakes at 5am then the total time slept is 7 hours. But if the user sleeps at 1am and wakes at 5, then the total hours slept is 4 hours.

I am slow at math so I need the help of you smart folks. Thanks.

Comment: If you could show what you have tried and what did not work out for you, that would definitely help to answer. Describing a specific problem you are having would also help. Otherwise use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) / [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the sample data and the data layout of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `DATEDIFF`
From the msdn page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx
So, for example, get a date and add to that date 5 hours:

```
DECLARE @D1 AS DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @D2 AS DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR,5,GETDATE())

SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,@D1,@D2)
```

DATEDIFF also allows to check DAYS, MINUTES etc...

And finally, if you don't have the Date stored in the DB, you can use

```
CAST
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
select CAST('2014-07-01 19:25:00' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user can insert the sleep and wake times in just numbers and not the datetime formats then it should be simple to calculate the sleep hours. And it better be a 24 hour format. For example if the user sleeps at 22:00 hrs and wakes up at 05:00 hrs then it is 7 hrs sleep time.

```
DECLARE @D1 AS INT = 22
DECLARE @D2 AS INT = 5

SELECT (24 - @D1) + @D2
```

Answer (score 0):

Its always tricky working with datetime and to avoid any mistakes I prefer leaving the complicated stuff to be performed by SQL itself. My solution accepts 24hr format in HHMM and outputs result as HH:MM. Hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @D1 AS VARCHAR(4) = 2002
DECLARE @D2 AS VARCHAR(4) = 530
DECLARE @dtD1 DATETIME
DECLARE @dtD2 DATETIME
DECLARE @SecondsSlept BIGINT

SET @D1 = RIGHT('0000' + @D1, 4)
SET @D2 = RIGHT('0000' + @D2, 4)

SET @dtD1 = STUFF(
        STUFF('20000101 00:00:00.000', 10, 2, LEFT(@D1, 2)),
        13,
        2,
        RIGHT(@D1, 2)
    )

SET @dtD2 = STUFF(
        STUFF('20000101 00:00:00.000', 10, 2, LEFT(@D2, 2)),
        13,
        2,
        RIGHT(@D2, 2)
    )


IF @dtD2 < @dtD1
    SET @dtD2 = DATEADD(dd, 1, @dtD2)

SET @SecondsSlept = DATEDIFF(s, @dtD1, @dtD2)

SELECT   CONVERT(
             VARCHAR(5),
             DATEADD(s, @SecondsSlept, '20000101 00:00:00.000'),
             114
         )
```